# Как сделать blur всего экрана[Unity C#]

Tags: c#, unity3d, graphics

Есть игра.По нажатию на Escape игра становится на паузу.Как без покупки про версии сделать блюр на всем экране, но не затронув само меню?(меню-GUIImage с кликабельными GUIText)

Comment: загугли Blur shader, много интересного найдешь

Comment: Так он же про версию юнити требует, не?

Comment: Вы в каком году живете? Unity полностью беплатная стала в 15году. Там только мелкие особенности, не связанные с движком остались в платной.

Comment: @Xumera_hZ, у меня юнити 4, а документация говорит что Blur и Blur Effect есть только в плаьной версии.

Comment: Когда задаете вопросы, пишите версию юнити и платформу ОС. Не знаю как сейчас, может в версиях unity 4 которые после 2015 года были выпущены есть доступ к Blur, надо проверять. А вы какую используете?

Comment: У меня юнити 4.1.5 вроде.На более новых MonoDevelop не компилирует скрипты.

Comment: Ну тут выбор за вами, либо пишите свой шейдер, либо возьмите смелость и перейдите на версию повыше

Comment: а если не можешь ни того ни другого?cg еще учить надо), а на новые версии не могу,монодевелоп не компилирует скрипты так как требует .net Framework v.5, но у меня XP.

Comment: А ты что хочешь? cg учить - нет. Менять версию - нет. Купить Pro версию - нет. На дворе почти 2018, че тогда уж не на 95ой винде, да на пентиуме 3ем?(а потом жаловаться, что юнити лагает)

Comment: 1.Учить cg-нормально, просто довольно долго, так как к нему еще и С надо бы выучить.2.У меня не лагает юнити)